# recursion c# how it works?

Tags: c#, recursion

I wanted to get the summary of all array elements by using recursion
Here is the code.

```
   static int SummaryOfArray(int[]myArray, int i = 0, int result = 0)
    {
        

        result += myArray[i];
        i++;
        if (i >= myArray.Length)
        {
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
          SummaryOfArray(myArray, i,result);     //<---if I put the "result =" on the top here 
            return result;
        }

         
           

    }




    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] arr = { 3, 2, 5};

       
        Console.WriteLine(SummaryOfArray(arr));
    }
```

If I put the "result =" on the front of the code my program works well and gives
the correct summary of the array elements,
but if I delete it gives me "3" as the result.
But why??? I don't understand at all, I watched lots of materials and videos
about the recursion, but I still do not understand why.
I understand the "last in last out" but why does the "result" changes from 10 to 3
at the end?

Comment: Set a breakpoint. Debug. Hint: `int` is a value type, so a copy is passed to `SummaryOfArray` in the nested call. That leaves you with `result += myArray[i];`.

Comment: And debug the code.

Comment: Think about the classic recursion example; `fib(n) => fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);`. The first call to `fib` returns the final result. In your case you want `SummaryOfArray` to return the first value, plus the sum of the remaining rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   static int SummaryOfArray(int[] myArray, int i = 0, int result = 0)
{
    if(myArray.Length == i) return result;
    else  return  SummaryOfArray(myArray,i+1,result+myArray[i] );  
}
```

Try it.